# How to open new sub-page of a project in same tab or new tab?

Tags: jquery, html

I have made single page website, it scroll when click on navigation bar to its respective sections, And I have applied script for that,

//smooth scroll to href value

```
jQuery(".tabs-btn ul li a, .navbar-nav li a, .navbar-brand").click(function(event){
                 event.preventDefault();
                 //calculate destination place
                 var dest=0;
                 if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
                      dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
                 }else{
                      dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
                 }
                 //go to destination
                 jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
             });
```

and my navigation is like,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#experience">skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team">our team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact-us">contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="career.html" target="_self">career</a></li>

                  </ul>
```

Now, because of script it is not going to next page by clicking on "career",
What can I do to open career.html in same tab or new by clicking on it.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you tried  target="_blank" on career.html link ? @RohitPatne

Comment: yes I did, and it did not work, as per user2896976 answer below it worked but by scroll animation stopped working

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".tabs-btn ul li a, .navbar-nav li a, .navbar-brand").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dest = 0;
    if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    } else {
        dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
    }
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: dest
    }, 1000, 'swing');
});
```

You're calling `event.preventDefault();` which is causing the link action to get ignored. If you want to smooth scroll on #anchor links, but let regular links work as normal, then you could check if the first character of the href is a `#`.

`$(event).target.attr("href").startsWith("#")`

Comment: it is working but  jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing'); is not working, after click it just go to target section without scroll effect

Comment: I tried 2 ways by applying if condition and this one, jQuery(".tabs-btn ul li a, .navbar-nav li a, .navbar-brand", $(event).target.attr("href").startsWith("#")).click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
       dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
       dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     
     //go to destination
     jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
    }) ; I know i am doing it wrong.

Comment: You want your condition to be inside the function: https://jsfiddle.net/e6h8jckr/

Comment: still no scroll effect

Comment: also error is showing in console " Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined"  Every time when I click on navigation tab